# Hypergeometric Distribution : probability that more than half is good

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

To simplify the context, let's say that **34 % of people are ugly**. haha...

lets take a sample of 15 people. (n = 15)

a) What is the probability that 3 or less out of the 15 are ugly ?

I went on and computed $P(0) + P(1) + P(2) + P(3)$ and it gives the same result I found with [this calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/hypergeometric.aspx)

b) - Find the average of ugly people in the sample ?

I used $n {K\over N}$ and found : $9.9$%

- Find the variation

I used $n{K\over N}{(N-K)\over N}{N-n\over N-1}$ and found $0.306*0.859$.

**what should be my answer to the variation question ?** is it 0.2623 or 26.23 % ?

**c) What is the probability that more than half of the sample are ugly ?**

**Here is my question : Is there a faster way to find C, than doing :** $P(0) + ... + P(8)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:  if you say 34% of people are ugly, then this represents a population proportion.  In order to use a hypergeometric distribution model, your sample would have to have an exact, known number of people who are ugly; e.g., 15 people are selected, 5 of which are ugly, and 10 of which are not.  Of those 15 people sampled, you select $m$ without replacement.  What is the probability that you obtain $3$ or fewer ugly people out of the $m$ selected?  This would be hypergeometrically distributed.  But in your case, 34% of 15 is 5.1, not 5; furthermore, you are asking about the distribution of the total number of ugly people in the sample of 15.  Therefore the hypergeometric model does not apply.

Instead, what you have is a *binomial* model.  We suppose that the population of individuals from which you have taken the sample is large enough that the sampling can be considered to have taken place with replacement: i.e., the number of ugly people in the sample follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n = 15$, $p = 0.34$.  Then the probability that no more than $3$ people are found to be ugly is simply $$\Pr[X \le 3] = \sum_{k=0}^3 \binom{15}{k} (0.34)^k (1 - 0.34)^{15-k}.$$

The mean and variance of the binomial distribution is $${\rm E}[X] = np = 15(0.34) = 5.1, \quad {\rm Var}[X] = np(1-p) = 3.366.$$

As for finding the probability that more than half of the sample is ugly--i.e., $X \ge 8$, we would have to compute $$\Pr[X \ge 8] = \sum_{k=8}^{15} \binom{15}{k} (0.34)^k (1-0.34)^{15-k}.$$  There isn't really a shorter way for such a small sample size.  If the sample size were larger, such that $np \ge 10$ and $n(1-p) \ge 10$, then we could use a Normal approximation to the binomial.  But in this case, we shouldn't.

Comment: Also, to clear up the apparent confusion with units in the first part of your question - variance isn't measured in %. Pure mathematics doesn't strictly speaking measure anything in any units, but if you're forced to assign a unit to it, then the most sensible choice is probably "square people", where square is used in the same sense as in "square metres". Since $V(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$, and $E(X)$ is measured in the same units as your random variable, this unit isn't completely nonsensical.

Comment: hmm I see. I though that 34% meant that 34 out of 100 were ugly. So I had 34 success and 66 fails in a pool of 100. Then I applied the formula. I also did that for a similar previous exercice, now I'm not sure if its good or not. It was 11% of something that was true or false. I assumed that 11 was the goods and 89 were bads, out of 100

Comment: yeah, it really looks like my other exercice is also binomial. thanks a lot @heropup. To sum it up, if I have a sample of things that are good or bad but it's a %, then it's binomial, else, if it's explicitly stated that it is x goods and y bads, then it is hypergeometric.